# What is the dimension of the coproduct of two abelian varieties?

Tags: abelian-varieties

Let's say I have two abelian varieties, $A$ and $B$, and I take their coproduct. My intuition says that $\dim(A+B) = \dim(A) + \dim(B)$. Is this accurate?

Comment: Which category are you working in? In the category of schemes/algebraic varieties, coproduct is disjoint union. In the category abelian varieties, it is the fibered product.